# How to do multiple imports in Python?

Tags: python, import, iterator, require

In Ruby, instead of repeating the "require" (the "import" in Python) word lots of times, I do

```
%w{lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 lib5}.each { |x| require x }
```

So it iterates over the set of "libs" and "require" (import) each one of them. Now I'm writing a Python script and I would like to do something like that. Is there a way to, or do I need to write "import" for all of them.

The straight-forward "traduction" would be something like the following code. Anyway, since Python does not import libs named as strings, it does not work.

```
requirements = [lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5]
for lib in requirements:
    import lib
```

Comment: Python actually does have a built-in function [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) which you can use to import a module named in a string. But it's meant to be called from the implementation of the `import` statement, not from user code. It certainly wouldn't be the proper solution in this case.

Comment: Oh! Really thanks for all the answers. Very good all of them.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

For known module, just separate them by commas:

```
import lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5
```

If you really need to programmatically import based on dynamic variables, a literal translation of your ruby would be:

```
modnames = "lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 lib5".split()
for lib in modnames:
    globals()[lib] = __import__(lib)
```

Though there's no need for this in your example.

Comment: Please note that the first code snippet defies Pep 8's recommendations https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
import lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5
```

You can also change the name they are imported under in this way, like so:

```
import lib1 as l1, lib2 as l2, lib3, lib4 as l4, lib5
```

Answer (score 17):

if you want multi-line:

```py
from englishapps.multiple.mainfile import (
    create_multiple_,
    get_data_for_multiple
)
```

Answer (score 10):

`import lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5`

Answer (score 6):

I just learned from a coworker today that, according to the [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), imports in Python should actually be written on separate lines:

```
import os
import sys
```

The style guide calls `import sys, os` wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can import from a string which contains your module name by using the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function.

```
requirements = [lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5]
for lib in requirements:
    x = __import__(lib)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `__import__` if you have a list of strings that represent modules, but it's probably cleaner if you follow the hint in the documentation and use `importlib.import_module` directly:

```
import importlib
requirements = [lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5]
imported_libs = {lib: importlib.import_module(lib) for lib in requirements}
```

You don't have the imported libraries as variables available this way but you could access them through the `imported_libs` dictionary:

```
>>> requirements = ['sys', 'itertools', 'collections', 'pickle']
>>> imported_libs = {lib: importlib.import_module(lib) for lib in requirements}
>>> imported_libs
{'collections': <module 'collections' from 'lib\\collections\\__init__.py'>,
 'itertools': <module 'itertools' (built-in)>,
 'pickle': <module 'pickle' from 'lib\\pickle.py'>,
 'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>}

>>> imported_libs['sys'].hexversion
50660592
```

You could also update your `globals` and then use them like they were imported "normally":

```
>>> globals().update(imported_libs)
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can import a list of libraries from a txt file in Python. It is very simple.

Example: If we have a text file libraries.txt content:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
```

Here is some sample code that demonstrates how to import a list of libraries from a txt file containing import statements:

```
with open('libraries.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    exec(line)
```