# Get modules in a module - Python

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have this structure:

```
project/
    sources/
        __init__.py
        source_one.py
        source_teo.py
    main.py
```

Then in `main.py`

```
import sources

# Here I'd like to get a list with [source_one, source_two]
```

Then import them dinamycally.

Is there any way to get this?

## EDIT

What I get from `dir(sources)`:

if I do `import sources` I get `['__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

If I do `from sources import *` I get `['__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

If I do `from sources import source_one` I get `['__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'source_one']`

But, I don't know the name of files in `sources` package, this is only an example. How can I find them?

Comment: `from sources import *` doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do to multiple imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260599/how-do-to-multiple-imports-in-python)

Comment: @RaminNietzsche Using `*` I could use `source_one` and `source_teo`. In this example, but I don't know what file will be in `sources`, so, sin I can not use them by name I need to get them dinamically in a list.

Comment: `dir(sources)` should tell you what's in there, and `source1 = __import__("source1", fromlist=(sources,))` should do the rest

Comment: @RaminNietzsche: Unless `sources` puts in extra work to support it, no, that actually doesn't work. Importing `*` from a package won't automatically load its submodules.

Comment: @Gocht How about `exec "import ..."` ?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I edited the question.

Comment: @RaminNietzsche I need the name to use `exec` the problem here is find the names of files in `sources`

Comment: Don't use `exec` - `__import__` should suffice (see my earlier comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of trick ;) but works:

```
import os
fileslist = os.listdir("sources")
for item in fileslist:
    if item.endswith("py") and item != "__init__.py":
        exec ("from sources.%s import *" %(item.split('.')[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

you should import relative to the current file location

Example :

1. `from sources.source_one import ClassSourceOne`
2. `from sources import *`

   In example 2, you can call the classes only by name_of_module.ClassName

Or you can use dynamicly import as shown here : [import dynamicly from package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707709/list-all-the-modules-that-are-part-of-a-python-package)

Also I recommend to import only the classes/modules you use that's why I recommend

```
from module import Class
```

And not using `import *` so it import all the module dependencies too

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the name of python files in `sources` that's why this should work dynamically.

Comment: To use classes in `source_one` by calling only `sources` -> `sources.Class_in_source_one` I need to add `from source_one import Class_in_source_one` in `__init__.py`. But, once again, I do not know the name of files in `sources`