# from module import func1, func2 as name1, name2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a nice way to do this without just listing each one on a separate line (like the working example below)?

```
from module import func1 as name1
from module import func2 as name2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do multiple imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260599/how-to-do-multiple-imports-in-python)

Comment: It's close, but it's ultimately not the same question. Though, had I seen it before I posted I might have been able to figure it out. However, because the problem is sufficiently different from my question, I feel like my question is valid and not duplicative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the attributes with aliases in one line:

```
from module import func1 as name1, func2 as name2
```

Comment: Can I get a 'That was easy' button?