# combine multiple libraries import with specific function import

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python you can import [multiple libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260643/6908282) at once and also you can import a [specific function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347226/6908282) from a library like below:

```py
import sys, os, csv
from shutil import copyfile
```

Is there a way to combine this?

For example, like this:

```py
import sys, os, csv, from shutil import copyfile
```

> Note, i'm aware that we can use [`shutil.copyfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439518/6908282), but I would like to use `copyFile` without `shutil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you NEED it in one line, you could use a semicolon

Such as:

`import sys, os, csv; from shutil import copyfile`

Comment: Oh, this is simple. Does this mean it cannot be imported using one import statement?

Comment: As far as I know, this would not be possible. Utilizing the semicolon basically combines two lines into one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `;`to add multiple statements in single lines in Python

```
import sys, os, csv; from shutil import copyfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to combine the imports in one line, you can do this :

```
import sys, os, csv; from shutil import copyfile
```

Just change de "," anfter csv to ";"

However, it is not recommended to do this.